# Filtering in Tablesorter. Unexpected behaviour

Tags: filter, tablesorter

In my tablesorter I applied this addParser to the column I'm showing here in this question. And it works well, but I found an unexpected behaviour when I filter in a way.

The results without filtering will be like this next picture:

[image]

The code for the addParser is the next one:

`$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id
    id: 'kilogramos',
    is: function(s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        // format your data for normalization
        return parseFloat(s.replace(' Kg','').replace('.',''));
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text
    type: 'numeric'
});`

If I use the ">=" it seems to apply the addParser, because I can get rid the "." and the " Kg" of and it finds the 11.689 Kg results.

[image]

But seems that if I don't use the operators  like ">", or ">=", etc. the behaviour change and it needs the dot to find what you are trying to get. In the next pictures I show what I mean.

[image]
In this last picture, I don't use the operators and I doesn't find any results. Instead, it needs now the "." and also even the " Kg" it works. The next image proves that:

[image]

I just don't want to need this "." or " Kg" to be used in any case.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: @Mottie If you could help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you're missing is a ["filter-parsed" class](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#classes) in the header ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/1811/))

```
<th class="sorter-kilogramos filter-parsed">Kg</th>
```